# Testing ios facebook hosted app links before release on app store

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, app-store, app-store-connect, applinks

My iphone app has mobile only content. I am using facebook app link hosts (https://graph.facebook.com/app/app_link_hosts) to create canonical urls which would be shared on facebook. The body for hosting request is:

```
"access_token=<APP_ACCESS_TOKEN>
            &ios=[
                    {\"url\":\"content://content/<content_id>\",
                    \"app_store_id\":<APP_STORE_ID>,
                    \"app_name\":\"<APP_NAME>\"}
            ]
            &name=link test
            &web={should_fallback:false}"
```

This works fine and it returns an id for the object. To test this i have shared:

```
https://fb.me/<canonical>
```

Since this app is not released yet, whenever i open the link from the facebook app it does not detect that my app is installed. It gives two action options, "Open web link" and "install APP_NAME". Both options point to a blank itunes link where the app will be. how do i test what my app does with this link before publishing the app on the app store?

this is the link returned:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/redirectToContent?id=APP_STORE_ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sweating it out, i have finally found the solution. The url scheme should be defined in the plist file. in this case "content" without the ://

Comment: How did you the App Store id for your app, if it is not published yet? I want to do the same, that is why I am asking. Thanks!